# Opencv 2.2 Face Detection Max Size

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

In opencv 2.2 the cvHaarDetectObjects function offers a max face size option. The problem is it doesn't seem to work. I am hoping somone can try it out, and let me know if I am just doing soemthing wrong or not. I am putting in a min face size detection of cvSize(30,30) and a max face size of cvSize(40,40), however it will still detect my face even if I take up the fullscreen, at say 300x300 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this feature does not work, there is a small bug in opencv's source code.